# Are iptables global or user ip specific?

Tags: linux, iptables

For example for my web server port I have the following rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 15 -j ACCEPT #If you spam concurrently for 15 times ++ you'll be blocked for 1 minute ~
```

Which basically if a user spams the refresh button on the browser or holds down F5, it will block them until that remaining 1/m interval is done.

My question is: When the limit is reached, the user cannot connect anymore. Does that mean ONLY that user cannot connect or does that mean port 80 is down for everyone else as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone. `limit` match has no additional qualifications.

`hashlimit` match is more configurable.

[iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) via [man iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html).

Note many "users" can be behind one IP (NAT, http proxy, CGNAT).

I have no idea what a best practice would be here.  But this implementation doesn't sound useful because HTTP supports persistent connections.  Apache mod_evasive would be better from that point of view.

If you *don't* use persistent connections, you'll get blocked immediately with that limit.  The [average website loads 100 resources](http://httparchive.org/trends.php) (!)

Comment: Thanks! I'll move to `hitcount` [instead!](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)